# Codeigniter index method return "index" for GET parameter if there is no parameter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have this part of code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function _remap($page){

            $this->index($page);
    }

    public function index($page = '1')
    {
        var_dump($page); exit;
    }
}
```

When i hit `domain/index.php/blog` **var_dump** returns me ﻿﻿﻿﻿`string(5) "index"` when i hit `domain/index.php/blog/2` it returns me 2, which is correct? But why ? I have default parameter `$page = '1'` ?

Comment: You have default parameter 1, if you don't define anything. So if you call just $this->index(); it'll return 1.

Comment: `$page = '1'` you can see it's default parameter only in case if you dont pass parameter, but it returns me `index` when i dont pass parameter, it's Codeigniter problem, but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I really can't understand what output you expect?

Comment: When i hit `domain/index.php/blog` it should return me 1 (default parameter) but it returns me `index` instead of 1, when i hit `domain/index.php/blog/2` it returns me right get parameter - 2

Comment: @D.Dimitrov това е проблем при Codeigniter, но и аз не знам как се решава ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit `domain/index.php/blog/2` this means you are calling blog controller's default method index and passing 2 as parameter. In this scenario it will replace your default parameter `$page = '1'` to 2.

When you will hit `domain/index.php/blog` then index function will be called without any parameters and it will take `$page` as 1.

**UPDATED ANSWER** (As per comment)

> If your controller contains a method named _remap(), it will always get called regardless of what your URI contains. It overrides the normal behavior in which the URI determines which method is called, allowing you to define your own method routing rules.

[Documentation Link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls)

Use below code it will resolve your issue.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function _remap($page){
        if($page=='index'){
            $this->index($page = 1);
        }
        $this->index($page);        
    }

    public function index($page = 1)
    {       
        var_dump($page); exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: This would be a normal behaviour, but when i hit `domain/index.php/blog` it returns me "index" instead of 1